# Stuck at IOS Push Notification (Testflight)

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I stuck at IOS push notification these few days. Here is my scenario:-

1. Using [Easy APNS Provider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-apns-provider-push-notification-service-testing-tool/id989622350?mt=12) and push notification by using aps.cer (download from App ID > Production SSL Certificate) , it can receive successfully.
   [image]
2. Using [APNS & GCM Online Tester](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/) and push notification by using .pem file (generated in keychain > export to .p12 > convert to .pem file) , it can receive successfully.
   [image]
3. Using [Push Tester](https://www.apnstester.com/apns/) and push notification by using .pem file (same as above), an error message will be shown as below.
   [image]
4. When putting the .pem file in my server end (PHP), it does not work as well. But it is fine when sandbox testing (developmentPush.pem).

Any idea, please help and alert me what I missed out. Appreciated!

Comment: try to send push from this and check http://pushtry.com/

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani i getting this error "_The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized_"

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: How do you get the device token? what function do you use?

Comment: @MohamedJaafar i get device token in this function:-_didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken_ -->  iOSDeviceToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

Comment: @henry, I think there is a problem with Apple's sandbox server, where it will not validate the development certificates. You are not the only one having this problem. I have submitted a bug report to Apple about it, but may I suggest you do the same just so they can see that the problem is not isolated. bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @BillNorman my case is in Production (testflight mode), sandbox ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, here are some steps to take care when perform IOS push notification:-

1. Enable server port / Request your server provider to enable APS port (example Port 2195)
2. Ensure push notification function is enable in Apple Connect
3. Change URL from gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 to gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195 in your backend server.
4. Make sure your APS key download and convert to .PEM file correctly.
5. **Do not mixed PRODUCTION and DEVELOPMENT device token together** when send it to APNS. It will cause failure as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue in export **.p12** certificate here I can see in export screenshot display **Export 2 items**.

> **Don't select the private key to an export .p12 certificate.**

[image]

**check with .p12**

> Can't Update the name of **Certificates**

[image]

Comment: HI Nikunj, may i know what u mean can't update the name of Certificates?

Comment: @henry I say that try with name **Certificates.p12** and one more thing before that remove the previous certificate and from key chain and download new one with check **bundleid** same as application bundle id.

Comment: Now I able to use Pushtry.com with .P12 file and it will sent out successfully. But when I try to use .pem file, I will get this error :- _pushcert.pem | 4460 | application/x-x509-ca-cert_

I use this to convert in terminal `openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
`

Comment: I tried the solution tat u posted and able to generate 2 separate files. But abit confuse how to combine it and become the final .pem file